# Sklearn TruncatedSVD not showing explained variance ration in descending order, or first number means something else?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svd

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD 

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data
X = X - X.mean() # centering the data

#### svd
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5)
svd.fit(X)
print(svd.explained_variance_ration)

####  PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(X)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

svd output is:

```
array([0.02049911, 0.1489056 , 0.13534811, 0.11738598, 0.08382797])
```

pca output is:

```
 array([0.14890594, 0.13618771, 0.11794594, 0.08409979, 0.05782415])
```

is there a bug in the TruncatedSVD implementation? or why is the first explained variance (0.02...) behaving like this? or what is the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary:

That is because `TruncatedSVD` and `PCA` use different `SVD` functions!.

Note: Your case is due to **Reason 2** below, yet I included another reason for future readers.

### Details:

**Reason 1: The solver set by user in each algorithm, is different**:

`PCA` internally uses [scipy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) which sorts singular values, hence the `explained_variance_ratio_` is sorted.

Part of Scikit Implementation of `PCA`:

```
# Center data
U, S, Vt = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
# flip eigenvectors' sign to enforce deterministic output
U, Vt = svd_flip(U, Vt)

components_ = Vt

# Get variance explained by singular values
explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
total_var = explained_variance_.sum()
explained_variance_ratio_ = explained_variance_ / total_var
```

Screenshot from the above-mentioned `scipy.linalg.svd` link:

[image]

On the other hand, `TruncatedSVD` uses [scipy.sparse.linalg.svds](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) which relies on the `ARPACK` solver for decomposition.

Screenshot from the above-mentioned `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` link:

[image]

---

**Reason 2: The `TruncatedSVD` operates differently compared to `PCA`:**

In your case you chose `randomized` as a solver (which is set by default) in both algorithms, yet you obtained different results with regards to the order of the variance.

That is because in `PCA`, the variance is obtained from the actual singular values (called `Sigma` or `S` in Scikit-Learn implementation), which are already sorted:

[image]

On the other hand, the variance in `TruncatedSVD` is obtained from `X_transformed` which results from multiplying the data matrix by the components. The latter does not necessarily preserve order because data are not centered, nor is it the purpose of `TruncatedSVD` which it is used in first place for sparse matrices:

[image]

Now if you center your data, you will get them sorted (note that you did not center data properly, because centering requires dividing by standard deviation):

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data

sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

### SVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5, algorithm='randomized', random_state=2021)
svd.fit(X)
print(svd.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

### Output

```
[0.12033916 0.09561054 0.08444415 0.06498406 0.04860093]
```

[Important: Further read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition).

Comment: nice detailed explanation, thank you. I was even going to add that both PCA and TruncatedSVD showing the same sorted explained_variance _ratio when I Standardscale the date, however, the components' strength in explaining the variance decreases as you saw the first one went from 14.5% to 12%.